# Пропадает интернет на сервере

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-10, администрирование, chromedriver

При завершении соединения с удаленным столом на windows 10, на нем как будто пропадает интернет? Почему думаю, что не работает интернет: скрипт который должен работать с сайтами не срабатывает, если я не подключен к серверу (в открывшемся браузере ошибка "Опаньки..." как обычно бывает при отсутствии интернета), если подключен, то все ок. С teamviewer такая же проблема, если не подключен, то ошибка "у вашего партнера нет доступа к интернету" Подскажите в чем может быть проблема, в каком направлении копать?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте отключиться от сервера с помощью создания файла `.bat` и запуска от имени администратора следующего скрипта:

```
for /f "tokens=4 delims= " %%G in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq tasklist.exe" /NH') do SET RDP_SESSION=%%G
tscon %RDP_SESSION% /dest:console
exit
```

После выполнения скрипта вас выкинет с RDP

Comment: можно подробнее, где создавать файл? просто создать блокнот с расширением .bat и в него поместить скрипт?

Comment: @ChikChirik все верно, сам файл можете положить куда угодно

Comment: @ChikChirik помогло?

Comment: меня должно выкинуть с RDP, а дальше что делать? просто заново подключиться и должно помочь?

Comment: вы запускаете батник - переключается сессия и удаленно выполняете ваш скрипт который не работает, подключаетесь заново - сессия вновь переключается, чтобы выйти нужно опять запустить батник. батник просто переключает сессию и дает возможность вашему скрипту работать без вашего подключения к RDP

Comment: Скажите, а чем отличается переключение сессии через батник от простого выхода с сервера?

Comment: тем, что команда tscon переключается RDP сессию на локальную сессию

Comment: Спасибо, завтра будет понятно сработал ли ваш вариант.

Comment: Не помогло ваше решение. Запустил свою программу она отработала и поставилась задержка на сутки, далее запустил ваш скрипт и меня как и должно было выкинуло с сервера, сегодня по истечению задержки ничего не произошло, повторно она не запустилась...

Comment: Не знаете в чем еще может быть дело?

Answer (score 1):

"Опаньки..." это не отсутствие интернета, а сбой при нехватке ОЗУ, либо же потеря дисплея при отключении от рдп. К примеру в консоли линукса с помощью Xvfb можно сделать виртуальный дисплей, либо запускать браузер с аргументом --headless.

Comment: Поставил больше ОЗУ на сервере, теперь ошибки 'опаньки' нет, скрипт как бы отрабатывает до конца, но по факту ничего не собирает. Сейчас ещё увеличил, поставил 6гб вместо 4. Не знаю в этом ли дело, так как что при 2, что при 4 гб, если я находился на сервере и запускал сам скрипт, то все работало корректно.

Comment: смотрите логи, где-то браузер должен ругаться. для работы браузера нужен дисплей, при рдп сессии он есть, а вот после отключения вряд ли... в линуксе можно создать виртуальный монитор, а в винде не подскажу, возможно единственный вариант запускать с флагом без дисплея. посмотрите ещё этот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180428/can-selenium-webdriver-open-browser-windows-silently-in-background